# MySQL installer console is executed in Commercial mode

Tags: mysql, installation, command-prompt

I have to install MySQL Server Community Edition version 5.6.x with silent installation. I planned to use `mysql-installer-community-5.6.26.0.msi` with `msiexec /i /quiet` command and run MySQLInstallerConsole.exe to install and configure the server silently.

I found a problem about MySQL installer while installing, it's always running in **Commercial mode** after installation. I tried to reinstall it again in many times via the same procedure but the results are not different.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f0xo.jpg]

How can I force the Installer to run in Community mode?

Answer (score 6):

It runs in commercial mode if the "MySQL Installer - Community" application has never been launched.

Running your command with "community" prefacing "install" should work.

```
MySQLInstallerConsole.exe community install server;5.6.24;x86:*:port=3306;rootpasswd=PASSWORD;servicename=MySQL -silent
```